# Riccati Equation in spot rate model

Tags: interest-rates, differential-equations, spot-rate

Given that $dr=(\eta-\gamma r)dt+\sqrt{\alpha r+\beta}dW$

Let $Z(r,t)=e^{A(t;T)-rB(t;T)}$,

\begin{matrix}
   \frac{dA}{dt}=\eta B-\frac{1}{2}\beta {{B}^{2}}  \\
   \frac{dB}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}\alpha {{B}^{2}}+\gamma B-1  \\
\end{matrix}

How can we solve for $B$ in this case?

$B$ is a Riccati Equation.
The answer for B is given below:

$B(t;T)=\frac{2(e^{\Psi_1(T-t)}-1)}{(\gamma+\Psi_1)(e^{\Psi_1(T-t)}-1)+2\Psi_1}$,

where $\Psi_1=\sqrt{\gamma^2+2\alpha}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noted, this is a Riccati type ODE and it can thus be simplified using the standard transformations for this class - see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation#Reduction_to_a_second_order_linear_equation). We start by defining

\begin{equation}
C(t, T) = \frac{1}{2} \alpha B(t, T) \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad C_t(t, T) = \frac{1}{2} \alpha B_t(t, t)
\end{equation}

and get

\begin{eqnarray}
C_t(t, T) & = & C^2(t, T) + \gamma C(t, T) - \frac{1}{2} \alpha.
\end{eqnarray}

We now set

\begin{eqnarray}
C(t, T) = -\frac{D_t(t, T)}{D(t, T)} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad C_t(t, T) & = & -\frac{D_{tt}(t, T)}{D(t, T)} + \frac{D_t^2(t, T)}{D^2(t, T)}\\
& = & \frac{-D_{tt}(t, T)}{D(t, T)} + C^2(t, T)
\end{eqnarray}

and get

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{D_{tt}(t, T)}{D(t, T)} & = & C^2(t, T) - C_t(t, T)\\
& = & -\gamma C(t, T) + \frac{1}{2} \alpha\\
& = & \gamma \frac{D_t(t, T)}{D(t, T)} + \frac{1}{2} \alpha
\end{eqnarray}

or

\begin{equation}
D_{tt}(t, T) = \gamma D_t(t, T) + \frac{1}{2} \alpha D(t, T).
\end{equation}

This is a homogeneous second order linear ODE with constant coefficients and can be solved using standard methods. We note that $T$ has been fixed and make another substitution by defining $\tau = T - t$ such that $E(\tau) = D(t, T)$. We get

\begin{equation}
E_{\tau \tau}(\tau) + \gamma E_\tau(\tau) - \frac{1}{2} \alpha E(\tau) = 0.
\end{equation}

The characteristic equation is

\begin{equation}
r^2 + \gamma r - \frac{1}{2} \alpha = 0
\end{equation}

with solutions

\begin{equation}
r_{1, 2} = -\frac{1}{2} \gamma \pm\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\gamma^2 + 2 \alpha} := \beta \pm \lambda.
\end{equation}

Note that $\lambda = \frac{1}{2} \psi_1$ in your notation. We thus have the general solution

\begin{equation}
E(\tau) = c_1 e^{(\beta + \lambda) \tau} + c_2 e^{(\beta - \lambda) \tau}
\end{equation}

with

\begin{equation}
E_\tau(\tau) = (\beta + \lambda) e^{(\beta + \lambda) \tau} + (\beta - \lambda) c_2 e^{(\beta - \lambda) \tau}
\end{equation}

and for some constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ that have to be determined. We obtain the solution to the Riccati ODE by substituting back

\begin{equation}
B(t, T) = \frac{2 C(t, T)}{\alpha} = -\frac{2 D_t(t, T)}{\alpha D(t, T)} = \frac{2 E_\tau(\tau)}{\alpha E(\tau)}.
\end{equation}

Applying the terminal condition yields

\begin{eqnarray}
B(T, T) = 0 \qquad & \Leftrightarrow & \qquad E_\tau(0) = 0\\
& \Leftrightarrow & \qquad c_1 = -c_2 \frac{\beta - \lambda}{\beta + \lambda}.
\end{eqnarray}

Thus

\begin{equation}
E(\tau) = \frac{c_2}{\beta + \lambda} e^{\beta \tau} \left( (\beta + \lambda) e^{-\lambda \tau} - (\beta - \lambda) e^{\lambda \tau} \right)
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
E_\tau(\tau) = (\beta - \lambda) c_2 e^{\beta \tau} \left( e^{-\lambda \tau} - e^{\lambda \tau} \right).
\end{equation}

We finally get

\begin{eqnarray}
B(t, T) & = & \frac{2 (\beta^2 - \lambda^2) \left( e^{-\lambda \tau} - e^{\lambda \tau} \right)}{\alpha \left( (\beta + \lambda) e^{-\lambda \tau} - (\beta - \lambda) e^{\lambda \tau} \right)}\\
& = & \frac{\left( e^{2 \lambda \tau} - 1 \right)}{(\beta + \lambda) - (\beta - \lambda) e^{2 \lambda \tau}}\\
& = & \frac{2 \left( e^{\psi_1 (T - t)} - 1 \right)}{\left( \gamma + \psi_1 \right) \left( e^{\psi_1 (T - t)} - 1 \right) + 2 \psi_1}.
\end{eqnarray}